# Comparing 3 column when first column is blank for some row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
I have a table test with 3 column A,B and C

A           B            C      
------------------------------
David       Dav         David       
Bill        Bill        Bill        
            Cathy       Cathy       
Rose        Ros         Ros 
            Mike        Mik     

  **Expected output**

  A         B           C       
  ----------------------------
  Rose      Ros         Ros     
            Mike        Mik
```

The logic here is When A is not blank then A compare with C else B compare with C

What I tried so far

```
  select * from test
  where a <> c
  or b <> c
```

But it is not giving me correct output, Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Its Blank not null

Comment: Btw: +1 for the question. There is sample data, expected output and own effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ISNULL`

```
select * from test
where isnull(nullif(a,''),b) <> c
```

Comment: Thanx Abdul its what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if A is not blank and making it a condition for the query to select, why don't you simply add the condition: !isnull(a)

```
select * from test
  where 
  !isnull(a)
  and (a <> c or b <> c)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion uses `CASE` with `LEN()`

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(A VARCHAR(100),B VARCHAR(100),C VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES      
 ('David','Dav','David')       
,('Bill','Bill','Bill')
,('','Cathy','Cathy')       
,('Rose','Ros','Ros') 
,('','Mike','Mik');

SELECT * 
FROM @Dummy 
WHERE CASE WHEN LEN(A)>0 THEN A ELSE B END <> C
```

### Hint

The biggest advantage of `LEN()` is its inherent abilities in dealing with `NULL` and blanks. `LEN` returns `0` when the value is `NULL`, when the value is an empty string and even if the value contains one or more blanks.